# SVN Commit to a different branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I Checked out a project from Trunk but now i need to commit the changes made in the working copy to a branch and not for the trunk(I made a lot of changes in multiple files).
What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save your work with svn diff or just copy working copy somwhere
2. use [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) for switch to branch
3. commit

Example:

```
svn switch "^/branches/my-branch" path-to-trunk-checkout
```